Moodle course images not loading
I upgraded our company-hosted Moodle LMS to most recent version 4.4.1+.
On upgrade (test) server is all running well.
After move to 3rd party hosting site runs, but all images (videos, etc.) in courses aren't loaded. Firefox Developer Tools says NS_ERROR_NET_PARTIAL_TRANSFER.
Error in Developer Tools
Address https://moodle.kvic.cz/pluginfile.php/5582/course/section/380/header_moodle3.png loads empty (maybe corrupted) picture instead of this Moodle course header
I suspect some kind of permission error.
What have I already tried - setting permissions for the moodledata folder to 0777, clearing all caches, clearing cookies in the browser.
Moodle version: 4.4.1+
Moodle theme: Boost
PHP version: 8.1.29
MariaDb version: 8.0.34

PHP setting max_input_vars set to 3000 due to third party hosting restrictions.
Can someone please advise me what else to try?

If you have moved to a different site, then you'll need to use the search and replace tool to update the links
go to http://yourmoodlesite.org/admin/tool/replace/index.php
See https://moodledev.io/docs/4.4/apis/plugintypes/local
